# libtool: what is the path to my module?

Tags: automake, libtool

I am creating a module from an autotools+libtool project:
The Makefile.am looks as follows

```
#the module:                                                     
lib_LTLIBRARIES = mmmm.la                                        
mmmm_la_SOURCES = mmmm.c                                 
mmmm_la_LDFLAGS = $(AM_LDFLAGS) -module -shared
```

Now, I want to write a C test for my module. The test should start loading the shared object mmmm.xx (where .xx is `.so` or `.la`)

What path should I give to `dlopen()` or `lt_dlopen()` in my C test?: The relative location of my module (compared to the test program) is different depending on whether I do make check, an out of tree make check, or a make installcheck...

I tried with `lt_dlopen()` hoping that the `-dlopen` option passed on the test `Makefile.am` would help autotools to locate the lib when `lt_dlopen()` is called, but it does not seem to help: `lt_dlopen()` can open the `.la` file, indeed, but one still have to tell where that file is located (possibly ommiting the .libs directory)

My test makefile looks like this when testing with the `ltdl` lib:

```
#the module test (tests are also installed, hence the "test" prefix)
test_PROGRAMS = tttt
tttt_SOURCES = tttt.c
tttt_LDADD = "-dlopen" mmmm.la
tttt_DEPENDENCIES = mmmm.la
```

Any good hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can deal with that is to set up the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable to where your library will be installed.

However, since you need it for the tests I will say export a variable from the `configure.ac` to the `config.h`. Thus, any file including the `config.h` would have a `#define your_variable` which can be used to set up the path for `dlopen`.

Comment: hmmm. both solutions sound like hacks, really: The idea of using libtool and autotools to start with is to abstract the OS as much as possible (be portable). If we end-up hard coding *.so filenames or LD_LIBRARY_PATH, we really are assuming a small subset of the OS we want to support (in clear, we code for linux!). But that may be the only (bad) solution. I will accept the answer, as I guess it would work, and you deserve some credit for trying :-) ... Not fully satisfied with it though...